# How to set InputType 'time' programmatically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, ime

I could set `InputType` 'time' in XML

```
<EditText
    android:inputType="time"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I need a keyboard, which shows `digits` and `colon(:)`. How to set `InputType` 'time' programmatically?

Comment: "et..setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT)" . Just like that

Comment: @ADM, but I could not find InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TIME or something like this

Comment: There is a input type as TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For [**`time`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html) field:

```
 setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME |InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME);
```

> datetime has dot(.), slash(/) which I do not want to show in keyboard

You should try with

```
setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789:"));
```

Comment: datetime has dot(.), slash(/) which I do not want to show in keyboard

Comment: @AndroidSmile.com `setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789."));`

Comment: This worked for me:        setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_DATETIME |InputType.TYPE_DATETIME_VARIATION_TIME);

Comment: @AndroidSmile.com Glad to hear. Move ahead .

Answer (score 1):

Set `digits` property in `EditText` in XML

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:digits="0123456789:"/>
```

Or you can set programmatically as,

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789:"));
```

Comment: Problem is I am adding EditText programmatically. How can I set digits programmatically?

Comment: And if it does help you then you can mark is a answer so it would be useful for others @AndroidSmile.com

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

- You can done with `programmatically` by adding this

---

```
editText.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789:"));
```